# How to append arrays in matrix?

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop

I have the following vectors:

```
a = 1:4;
b = zeros(8,8);
```

and I would like to append `a` in `b` in the following manner:

```
b = [1 2 3 4 0 0 0 0
    0 1 2 3 4 0 0 0
    0 0 1 2 3 4 0 0
    0 0 0 1 2 3 4 0
    0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 
    0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3
    0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

I want to achieve this using a for loop, so I tried:

```
for i = 2:size(b,1)
   b(i,i:length(a))=a; 
end
```

But I get the following error `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.`

Can anybody please help me solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `length(a)` as the second input to `:` (`i:length(a)`) which creates a vector of a different size every loop iteration

```
i = 1;
size(b(i, i:length(a)))
% 1   4

i = 2;
size(b(i, i:length(a)))
% 1   3
```

When you try to assign a four-element vector into this, there is obviously going to be a size mis-match. Instead, what you *really* want is `i + length(a) - 1`.

```
for i = 1:size(b, 1)
    b(i, i:(i + length(a) - 1)) = a;
end

b = b(:, 1:8);
```

That being said, a better option would be to use convolution (`conv2`) to replicate your values along the diagonal like this

```
tmp = conv2(a, eye(8));
output = tmp(:, 1:8);
```

Comment: Thank you. Using `conv2` works but how can I achieve this using the for loop?

Comment: @user161816 Also, why exactly do you *need* to use a for loop?

Comment: @user161816 Oops, I had a typo. Fixed

Comment: Thank you! It worked and the reason I couldn't use `conv2 method` because my zeros matrix is `2000*2544`, which is why I thought using for loop would be a good idea

Comment: @user161816 If your matrix is that size, then change the input to `eye` in the example I've shown. It is going to be *MUCH* faster than the for loop

Answer (score 4):

You can use `spdiags` function

```
spdiags(repmat(1:4,8,1),0:3,9,8)
```

that creates a sparse matrix and you can convert it to a dense matrix:

```
full(spdiags(repmat(1:4,8,1),0:3,9,8))
```

Result:

```
1   2   3   4   0   0   0   0
0   1   2   3   4   0   0   0
0   0   1   2   3   4   0   0
0   0   0   1   2   3   4   0
0   0   0   0   1   2   3   4
0   0   0   0   0   1   2   3
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   2
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I compared speed of `spdiags` with `conv2` in Octave:

```
disp('-------SPDIAGS-SPARSE----')
tic
spdiags(repmat(1:4,8000,1),0:3,8000,8000);
toc

disp('-------SPDIAGS-DENSE-----')
tic
full(spdiags(repmat(1:4,8000,1),0:3,8000,8000));
toc


disp('-------CONV2----------=--')
tic
tmp = conv2(1:4, eye(8000));
output = tmp(:, 1:8000);
toc
```

Result of comparison:

```
-------SPDIAGS-SPARSE----
Elapsed time is 0.005831 seconds.
-------SPDIAGS-DENSE-----
Elapsed time is 0.265963 seconds.
-------CONV2----------=--
Elapsed time is 1.6433 seconds.
```